# machine learning storing the classification results

Tags: database, machine-learning

I have some data set for [supervised learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning) task.

I would like to try different [statistical classifications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification) and to store the results for further analysis, in addition it would be great to store the results of the classification on the test data to see how the classification succeeded in different examples.

If there are any specific application to store the results of different classifications, such that I would specify the parameters of different classifications, do analysis afterwards, store the interesting examples and etc.

Of course, the first thought was to use DB, but when I try to realize how many different parameters each classification has I understand that there is going to be a really complicated scheme of DB.

So before creating such a scheme I am wondering whether there is something already created that you use for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply output the results to a CSV file, for example in the format:

```
index_of_instance,classification
```

and store them with filenames or dirs representing your parameter/design choices.
The name of the file can represent your parameters. Say you are running a random forest with *{100,200,500}* trees and *{0,10,20}* max depth. Your file names could be 100_0.csv, 200_0.csv, etc. You could also save the cross validation fold you're at, say: 0_100_0.csv. This way you can easily analyse your results later with a simple combination of unix commands, Excel, or more involved packages such as R.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, something very similar I do currently, I thought may be there is more scalable solution, when I try many different classification with many different parameters, DB approach might help, however the set of parameters for every classification is different, so it escalates easily.

Comment: No problem. This kaggle thread may be of some help: http://www.kaggle.com/forums/t/4815/how-to-manage-machine-learning-projects

Comment: I do something similar but have found that it's useful to provide the names of the parameters as well as their values in the filename, e.g., `trees=100,depth=10,fold=1.csv`. That way your eyes don't cross when you go back and look at your data after a month or two.